# Display graphics on top of OpenGL game

Tags: c#, opengl, overlay

This is not really language-specific (although I am most comfortable in C#). I am basically trying to create an application that would display basic 2D graphics over an OpenGL application (specifically FlightGear). There would be no need to have mouse-interaction (e.g. clicks) with the overlay - it would be for informational purposes only.

What is the simplest way of going about this?

Comment: Hi. Can you give me some feedback if my answer was helpfull for you or not? I wasn't sure if I got exactly what you wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you just have to render your scene and after that you can change your camera transformation to a parallel projection, with the size of your viewport. You can now render simple rectangles with your 2D graphics as textures on it.